# i'm trying to learn some dictioneries if thats how it's spelled in python, but i can't seem to fix this

Tags: python

> **i've tried using str() but it still doesent work, someone help please? thanks.**

images:

[code][1] ,
[error][2]

> zam = {'naem':'xx_gamerproytdev_xx', 'age':6, "gender":'dreamsexual', "whl":"dig"}
> print('heiz naem waz' (zam['naem']) + 'he liked' + (zam["whl"]) + 'his
> gender was' + (zam['gender']) + 'and he waz ' + str((zam['age'])))

**error**

```
SyntaxWarning: 'str' object is not callable; perhaps you missed a comma?
  print('heiz naem waz' (zam['naem']) + 'he liked' + (zam["whl"]) + 'his gender was' + (zam['gender']) + 'and he waz ' + str((zam['age'])))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hahag\Desktop\Python\main.py", line 79, in <module>
    print('heiz naem waz' (zam['naem']) + 'he liked' + (zam["whl"]) + 'his gender was' + (zam['gender']) + 'and he waz ' + str((zam['age'])))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

edit : this was long ago and ive got it fixed by myself
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuAVm.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sU7HE.png

Comment: error is `'heiz naem waz' (zam['naem'])` it's like `'somestring'()` as you would call it

Answer (score 1):

You missed a plus sign. It should be

```py
print('heiz naem waz' + (zam['naem']) …
```

[f strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) are a nicer way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a plus sign:

```
print('heiz naem waz' + (zam['naem']) + 'he liked' + (zam["whl"]) + 'his gender was' + (zam['gender']) + 'and he waz ' + str((zam['age'])))
```